# Cannot Set Up Naked Domain on Azure CDN

Tags: domain-name-system, azure, cdn, fqdn

What I am using:

- Azure CDN: `Premium Verizon`
- DNS: `DnsMadeEasy`

I am struggling to setup all endpoints of my domain on Azure CDN; I am able to set up endpoints with a prefix to my domain (i.e `prefix.mydomain.com`) but for the naked domain (`mydomain.com`) it doesn't work.

I have my CNAME records pointing to the CDN endpoint and for these hostnames it works fine. I am aware that an A record in DNS can only point to an IP, so instead am using DnsMadeEasy's ANAME record to point to the CDN (more info on ANAME [here](https://dnsmadeeasy.com/services/anamerecords/))

From the error I am seeing it looks like Azure is verifying the custom domain (the hostname I am trying to add) by checking the endpoint which `mydomain.com` is pointing too. Since DnsMadeEasy pre-populates an A record with whatever IP the ANAME resolves too (or at least I think that is what it does) Azure is failing the validation because it is getting the IP of the endpoint, thus not allowing me to add it.

Has anyone else seen this? Has anyone else added a naked domain to Azure CDN? Is this a bug in Azure CDN?

Comment: I'd just set up the apex to redirect to www.

Answer (score 3):

This is a common situation with services (not just Azure services) that perform naive DNS checks before allowing you to activate a service. They *require* a CNAME to be returned, but of course you can't put a CNAME at the apex, so you're forced to use a subdomain.

There is an [open feature request](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169397-cdn/suggestions/32993635-naked-domain-cdn) that you can throw some votes on to see if they'll ever action it. I've had mixed results with the Azure feedback forums.